# How to detect if CancellationToken was truly canceled

Tags: c#

Having this code after Task.Delay is done then `_tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested` is always true even if I didn't call cancel on that token.

My question is how to detect here that Task.Delay waited full time and was not cancelled?

```
var _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
await Task.Delay(5000, _tokenSource.Token);
```

Comment: the number in the constructor is the time after the cancellation is automatically emitted.
If you create a cancellationsource with 5 seconds and  wait 5 seconds, the cancellation is always requested after the wait of course.

Comment: you can put this as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the task completed due to the token being cancelled then the task will be canceled, and awaiting it will throw a TaskCanceledException.  If the delay completed without being prematurely canceled, it won't throw.  You can also store the `Task` returned by `Delay` in a variable and inspect `IsCanceled`, but you'd need to catch the task cancellation exception to even reach that code, so you'd already know.

Answer (score 2):

```
var _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(5000);
```

This will create a CancellationTokenSource that automatically cancels after 5000 milliseconds.

```
await Task.Delay(5000, _tokenSource.Token);
```

Here, you wait 5000 milliseconds.
So, after the delay the cancellation is always automatically cancelled, because the token source was constructed this way.

Comment: ok but can i this way detect that thread waited full deleay 5s and was not canceled ? I belive having var _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(6000); and await Task.Delay(5000, _tokenSource.Token); and when somone cancel the token then the value IsCancellationRequested will be also false even longer

Comment: "and was not canceled" - the cancellation token *is* cancelled after 5s. It wasn't cancelled by calling Cancel, but it's still cancelled, automatically. Any claim that calling `Cancel()` and then the cancellation token *not* showing a cancellation request is the opposite situation from what you've shown so far, so it's really not clear what you're asking about.

Comment: If you're asking if you can detect if an explicit call to .Cancel in your code was done, as opposed to the CTS cancelling itself after time elapsed, then no, there is no such mechanism made available.

Comment: Also note that if you're debugging the code, and spend more than 5 seconds stepping through the code, time is of course flowing for the CTS as well. This could mean that code that normally would never see a cancelled token might see it during debugging.